# Validating content pages using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-easyui

I have a master page in which  i have created a placeHolder like

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MasterContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

I have a content pages which inherits this master page. In that content page I have added a `<form>` and some asp controls

During validating this form using  easyui jquery as `if ($("#frm").form('validate'))` its always returning **true** even if rules attached(required,email validations) to asp textboxes are not met.

I have the notion that since content pages are addded dynamically to masterpage I have to inform the DOM parser that a new form is added.
My belief is based on the below code
`console.log($("#frm").html())` is not printing anything on console

How can I inform the DOM parser that a new element has been added

My ultimate aim is to validate the form in content page

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bind DOMSubtreemodified, for instance:

```
$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
   console.log("modified..");
});
```